# How to add and remove table rows Dynamically in React-native

Tags: react-native

I would like to develop a table which has the functionality to add and delete row dynamically. As I am new to react native and I am not able to add the dynamic add and removing of table rows.

I have tried the code but its not working and cannot able to create the exact solution what I need

I am expecting the table to be like
Visit https://3vk7jxv69p.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Can you share your existing code?

Comment: Unfortunately I have deleted the whole code as unable to get it. @JebinBenny

Answer (score 0):

By adjusting array of data, you can add, delete items.
eg:

```
_addRow=(item)=> {
   let dataArray = this.state.data;
   dataArray.push(item);
   this.setState({data: dataArray});
}

_removeRow=(index)=> {
   let dataArray = this.state.data;
   dataArray.splice(index, 1);
   this.setState({data: dataArray});
}

_removeLastRow=()=> {
   let dataArray = this.state.data;
   dataArray.splice(dataArray.length - 1, 1);
   this.setState({data: dataArray});
}

render() {
    return (
       ...
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={this._renderItems}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            extraData = {this.state}
          />
       ...
    );
}
```